# Using xpath to extract data from an XML column in postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, xml-parsing

I've made the following table:

```
create table temp.promotions_xml(id serial promotion_xml xml);
```

I've inserted the following data into temp.promotions:

```
<promotions xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/promotion/2008-01-31">
    <campaign campaign-id="2013-1st-semester-jet-giveaways">
        <description>2013 1st Semester Jet Giveaways</description>
        <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>
        <start-date>2013-01-01T05:00:00.000Z</start-date>
        <end-date>2013-07-01T04:00:00.000Z</end-date>
        <customer-groups>
            <customer-group group-id="Everyone"/>
        </customer-groups>
    </campaign>
</promotions>
```

The data is in the table.

I can't figure out how to get it out.  I probably will want to be able to populate a relational model that I will build, so I want to get rid of all the tag's.

Below are a few queries that I've tried that don't work.  I pretty sure that I am just dancing around the correct syntax.  These queries return rows of empty sets.

FWIW, we are using Postgres 9.0.4.

Thanks,  --sw

```
select xpath('/promotions/campaign/description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('./promotions/campaign/description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('promotions/campaign/description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('///description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('//description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('.//description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('./campaign/description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
select xpath('//campaign/description/text()',promotion_xml) textcol from temp.promotions_xml
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works:

```sql
WITH tbl(p_xml) AS (  -- CTE just to provide test table with xml value
   SELECT '<promotions xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/promotion/2008-01-31">
              <campaign campaign-id="2013-1st-semester-jet-giveaways">
                 <description>2013 1st Semester Jet Giveaways</description>
                 <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>
                 <start-date>2013-01-01T05:00:00.000Z</start-date>
                 <end-date>2013-07-01T04:00:00.000Z</end-date>
                 <customer-groups>
                    <customer-group group-id="Everyone"/>
                 </customer-groups>
              </campaign>
           </promotions>'::xml
    )  -- end of CTE, the rest is the solution
SELECT xpath('/n:promotions/n:campaign/n:description/text()', p_xml
           , '{{n,http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/promotion/2008-01-31}}')
FROM   tbl;
```

Returns:

```sql
{"2013 1st Semester Jet Giveaways"}
```

Note how I assign the **namespace alias** `n` for your namespace in the [third argument of `xpath()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) and use it at every level of the xpath.

If you remove the XML namespace from the document, everything becomes much simpler:

```sql
WITH tbl(p_xml) AS (  -- not the missing namespace below
   SELECT '<promotions>
              <campaign campaign-id="2013-1st-semester-jet-giveaways">
                 <description>2013 1st Semester Jet Giveaways</description>
                 <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>
                 <start-date>2013-01-01T05:00:00.000Z</start-date>
                 <end-date>2013-07-01T04:00:00.000Z</end-date>
                 <customer-groups>
                    <customer-group group-id="Everyone"/>
                 </customer-groups>
              </campaign>
           </promotions>'::xml
   )
SELECT xpath('/promotions/campaign/description/text()', p_xml)
FROM   tbl;
```

`<rant>` Is it just me or is everybody happy about [`json` and `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html), so we don't have to deal with XML.`</rant>`

Comment: Great answer, worked for me when trying to xpath out info with namespaces involved! I agree parsing json can be a lot easier as well.

Comment: It's not just you. But it's not me... in all cases. Sometimes XML is just better: https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlorb/entry/analysis_of_json_use_cases

Comment: Having read the oracle blog, I'm even more convinced that JSON is always the way :-). jsonb is a great addition to Postsgres.