# how to extract value from xml payload that is stored in a table using PGSQL?

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a table which has a column xml_payload. It has below data.

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.08">
<BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
<GrpHdr>
<MsgId>XX2023050820230508USIn00063461</MsgId>
<CreDtTm>2023-05-08T12:14:49.358Z</CreDtTm>
</GrpHdr>
</BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
</Document>
```

How I redrive CreDtTm node value using pgsql?

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('./BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/GrpHdr/CreDtTm/text()', xml_payload))
  from wire.stages
```

Comment: Does the `xpath` work?

Comment: no it does not, hence looking for solution.

Comment: And *what* does not work about it? Is there a syntax error, does it just return the wrong data, or does it return no data? Or something else?

Comment: Declare the namespace. See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800646/3710053

Answer (score 0):

Your XML example contains namespace declaration that affects the XPath expression, as it needs to take the namespace into account.
To retrieve the text content of the  element try query like this one

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//*[local-name()="Document"]/*[local-name()="BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn"]/*[local-name()="GrpHdr"]/*[local-name()="CreDtTm"]/text()', xml_data::xml))
FROM stages;
```

Result

```
--------------------------
 2023-05-08T12:14:49.358Z
(1 row)
```